# Bash script doesn't wait for background jobs to finish

Tags: bash, wait, background-process

I'm having some troubles with multiprocessing with BASH.

I have a function that is doing this:

```
#Fait appel au script SSH pour le passage de commandes
sendSSHrequests() {
    temp_info=$($mysql --skip-column-names -h $db_address -P $db_port -u $db_user -p$db_passwd $db_name -e "select $db_site_table.code_site, ip_routeur, operateur, hostname from $db_site_table, $db_routeur_table where $db_site_table.code_site=$db_routeur_table.code_site and $db_site_table.ip_routeur NOT IN (select ip from $db_erreur_table) AND $db_site_table.code_site REGEXP '([GM][0-9]$)';")
    while read codesite ip operateur hostname
    do 
        (sleep 3; /usr/bin/perl $DIR/GSU-RTR-sshscript.pl $codesite $ip $operateur $hostname) &
        ((current_proc_ssh++))
        if [ $current_proc_ssh -eq $max_proc_ssh ]; then
            printf "Pausing with $max_proc_ssh processes...\n"
            current_proc_ssh=0
            wait
        fi
    done<<<"$temp_info"
    wait
}
```

But actually, this `wait` is not working. How can I see it? Because in my "main" part I have this:

```
echo "----------------------demarrage---------------------------------"
date
sendSSHrequests
sh $DIR/GSU-RTR-recursiveCall.sh
echo "-------------------------fin------------------------------------"
```

And when the function **sendSSHrequests** is still using the child processes, I have outputs from the script **GSU-RTR-recursiveCall.sh**

Comment: Just in case - is `$temp_info` being populated correctly (i.e. is the `mysql` call returning results)?

Comment: Yes it is. The where conditions make sure that the router is not declared "error" in the table error. If not, the informations are 100% reliable

Comment: Consider using GNU Parallel - it is ideally suited to this task.

Comment: Guess i have no choice...

Comment: Where do you set `max_proc_ssh` ?

Comment: What does `GSU-RTR-sshscript.pl` do? Does it leave behind background jobs before exiting? You script can only `wait` on jobs that it creates, not processes that its children create.

Answer (score 0):

You have to collect the PID of this process:`/usr/bin/perl $DIR/GSU-RTR-sshscript.pl $codesite $ip $operateur $hostname` and then `wait` on that PID.

To collect the various PIDS in the while loop you have to set variables dynamically using `eval`, please try the following solution:

```
#Fait appel au script SSH pour le passage de commandes
sendSSHrequests() {
    temp_info=$($mysql --skip-column-names -h $db_address -P $db_port -u $db_user -p$db_passwd $db_name -e "select $db_site_table.code_site, ip_routeur, operateur, hostname from $db_site_table, $db_routeur_table where $db_site_table.code_site=$db_routeur_table.code_site and $db_site_table.ip_routeur NOT IN (select ip from $db_erreur_table) AND $db_site_table.code_site REGEXP '([GM][0-9]$)';")
    while read codesite ip operateur hostname
    do 
        (sleep 3; /usr/bin/perl $DIR/GSU-RTR-sshscript.pl $codesite $ip $operateur $hostname; MY_PID=$!; eval $(printf "pid_$codesite_$ip_$operateur_$hostname=$MYPID")) &
        ((current_proc_ssh++))
        if [ $current_proc_ssh -eq $max_proc_ssh ]; then
            printf "Pausing with $max_proc_ssh processes...\n"
            current_proc_ssh=0
        fi
    done<<<"$temp_info"

    ####### I added the following loop ########
    while read codesite ip operateur hostname
    do
        wait pid_$codesite_$ip_$operateur_$hostname
    done<<<"$temp_info"


}
```

I removed your `wait` commands and collected some pids in the first `while` cycle, then added another `while` cycle similar to the first where i waited for those PIDS to terminate.